# BizTalk server Virtual Machine - Unable to see sql server and visual studio

Tags: azure, biztalk, azure-virtual-machine, iaas

I created a BizTalk server Virtual Machine in azure portal(BizTalk server 2013 standard), but I am not able to see the sql server(but I can see SQL server management studio there)and visual studio in the vm. Do I need to install sql server and visual studio manually on a biztalk server Virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

If both SQL Management Studio and Visual Studio are there, then you must have provisioned an MSDN instance, meaning a full DEV instance.

That means SQL Server is installed.  Did you try to connect to SQL Server?  You can try '.' or the server name itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at using Biztalk on Azure recently too, and from what I understand it sounds like you only got a Biztalk Server VM, and not the DEV environment.

In that case you would need to get another VM to host SQL Server, and none of these two VM will have Visual Studio installed (see section "Biztalk Server License Options" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj248689.aspx).

If what you need is a the full dev environment ready to use, then you need one of the MSDN subscriptions listed as "Full Benefits" here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/how-to-buy-vs.aspx

Then again, I've been looking into this stuff recently so I could be wrong.